# Joining files awk

Tags: join, awk

I have two files:

```
FILE A
12  999900  1
12  999901  1
12  999902  1
12  999903  1
12  999904  1
12  999905  1
12  999906  1
12  999907  1
12  999908  2
12  999909  2
12  999910  2
12  999911  2
12  999912  2

FILE B

#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  Carolyn
12  1000010 .   G   A   221 .   DP=9;VDB=0.0298;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,4,5;MQ=60;FQ=-54    GT:PL:DP:GQ 1/1:254,27,0:9:51
12  1000482 .   G   A   117 .   DP=7;VDB=0.0398;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,1,4;MQ=60;FQ=-42    GT:PL:DP:GQ 1/1:150,15,0:5:27
12  1001152 .   T   C   127 .   DP=10;VDB=0.0392;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,4,6;MQ=58;FQ=-57   GT:PL:DP:GQ
```

I'd like to write an AWK script that compares $2 in file A and $2 in file B. The output should be like file A but with another column. If $2 from file A and B match, the 4th column should say "match!".

NOTE: FILE A has a lot more rows than FILE B.

Is that possible??

Comment: Is the second column of each file sorted?

Comment: yes, it is. but join command doesn't work... it throws an error

Comment: It throws: "join: depth_Carolyn.txt:101: is not sorted: 12 1000000 11"
but it is sorted.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
cat f1
12  999900  1
12  999901  1
12  999902  1
12  999903  1
12  999904  1
12  999905  1
12  999906  1
12  999907  1
12  999908  2
12  999909  2
12  999910  2
12  999911  2
12  999912  2
```

```
cat f2
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  Carolyn
12  1000010 .   G   A   221 .   DP=9;VDB=0.0298;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,4,5;MQ=60;FQ=-54    GT:PL:DP:GQ 1/1:254,27,0:9:51
12   999909 .   G   A   117 .   DP=7;VDB=0.0398;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,1,4;MQ=60;FQ=-42    GT:PL:DP:GQ 1/1:150,15,0:5:27
12  1001152 .   T   C   127 .   DP=10;VDB=0.0392;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,4,6;MQ=58;FQ=-57   GT:PL:DP:GQ
```

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$2];next} $2 in a {$0=$0 " match!"} 1' f2 f1
12  999900  1
12  999901  1
12  999902  1
12  999903  1
12  999904  1
12  999905  1
12  999906  1
12  999907  1
12  999908  2
12  999909  2 match!
12  999910  2
12  999911  2
12  999912  2
```

---

How it works

```
awk '
    FNR==NR {               # Run this section for f2 file
        a[$2]               # store record #2 in array a
        next}               # skip to next record
    $2 in a {               # if $2 in file f1 is found in array a
        $0=$0 " match!"     # change record to show the match
        }
    1                       # do the default action, print $0
    ' f2 f1                 # the two input files
```

Comment: could you explain a little, please?? This way I understand instead of copy&paste.

Comment: This very basic `awk` `array`, so you should find many example here and other places on how this works.  Updated my post.

Comment: I concur with @BMW that the `++` doesn't seem to do anything.  Arrays in AWK are basically like a `dict` in Python, and you are just relying on the uniqueness of the values in field 2.

Comment: If really picky, even `(` and `)` can be removed. So it can be: `awk 'FNR==NR {a[$2];next} $2 in a {$0=$0 " match!"} 1' f2 f1`

Comment: Updated post, removed `++`  and parentheses.